# Why was a seemingly valid answer in "What is the bounty of Gol D. Roger?" got deleted?

Tags: discussion

In [What is the bounty of Gol D. Roger?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/42582/what-is-the-bounty-of-gol-d-roger), there was an answer posted by a new user stating a crude, direct answer to the question.

The original revision might look low-quality since it only stated the rounded bounty amount, a fluff about a bounty poster, and a source link. Though, the source link contains more details like the chapter number (which I have cross-checked with the Wikia), the bounty poster itself, and other members' bounty (which is unrelated to this case).

After some revisions by others (including me), the answer included the chapter number, the actual bounty amount, and the bounty poster, making the post standalone.

After some time, I noticed the answer was deleted, and looking from the last active, presumably by a mod.

I'm curious if I missed something about the post deserving to be deleted, without revealing any sensitive/mods-only info (if any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user was found to be promoting [his blog](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/218661) without proper disclosure and flagged as spam for the most part. The link was removed.